# PHP string replace question

Tags: php, string, replace

If I have a string that equals "firstpart".$unknown_var."secondpart", how can I delete everything between "firstpart" and "secondpart" (on a page that does not know the value of $unknown_var)?

Thanks.

Neel

Comment: Specify the pattern of the string contained in `$unknown_var`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[substr_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php)

start and length can be computed with [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php).  Or you could go the regex route if you're comfortable learning about them.

Comment: substr_replace is substantially faster than regex (although less pretty).  Upvoted.

Comment: @Neel: If you actually have a variable "$unknown_var", you could simply do "str_replace($unknown_var,'',$str);", but I assume you just used that to ask your question.  Go with Colithium's answer :-)

Comment: @Chris: One more question: how do I use substr_replace? I tried doing $data = substr_replace($old_data, '', $strpos1, $strpos2) but it deleted too much. I added the length of "firstpart" to $strpos1. $strpos1 is 250 and $strpos2 is 520.

Comment: The argument list is substr_replace([string],[replacement],[starting position], [length]), so in your case, it should be:

$data = substr_replace($old_data,'',$strpos1,$strpos2-$strpos1);

Answer (score 1):

As long as `$unkonwn_var` does not contain neither `firstpart` nor `secondpart,` you can match against

```
firstpart(.*)secondpart
```

and replace it with

```
firstpartsecondpart
```

Answer (score 0):

You shoukd use a regexp to do so.

```
preg_replace('/firspart(.*)secondpart/','firstpartsecondpart',$yourstring);
```

will replace  anything between the first occurence of firstpart and the last of secondpart, if you want to delete multiple time between first and second part you can make the expression ungreedy by replacing `(.*)` by `(.*?)` in the expression

```
preg_replace('/firspart(.*?)secondpart/','firstpartsecondpart',$yourstring);
```